# Run RMI Registry with Java code

Tags: java, rmi

Is there any way to run RMIregistry through Java code? Is this possible or I can only do it through NetBeans or Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Of course you can run RMI without NetBeans or Eclipse.  Those are just IDEs.  RMI is older than both.

Comment: What i'm trying to find is not a YES, IT CAN or NO, IT CAN'T. I'm wondering how to do it

Comment: To run a Java code needs the code, so post the code you want to run.

Comment: You can run *any* Java code without an IDE. How do you think production systems are suppose to work? and what difference is adding RMI into it supposed to make? Not a real question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, i was trying to ask about rmiregistry and not rmi applications

Comment: rmiregistry included with jdk, so you don't need IDE for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that we know what you actually want, call LocateRegistry.createRegistry(), but I really feel you could have found that for yourself with a little research.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, here's the tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html